# Classic Design to Modern Design conversion

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-masterpage, modern-experience, conversion, classic

We have moved from On-Prem to Online through a migration, the designers have given us everything based on Classic Masterpages which includes custom design. I was wondering if we can carry over any of the existing design to the Modern look as we really like the new features available on the Document Libraries.

Or is SharePoint saying you can do one or the other but not both with the same design. So if we wanted some Site Collections to have Modern functionality, but other Site Collections to have the Classic Functionality is it possible to get them both to look the same with a custom design?

Also is there a graphical layout of the masterpage element id names that would make it easier to identify where to customise.

MTIA

Comment: Welcome to SP.SE! This is a good question, but you might want edit in your primary question/issue (probably "can on-prem masterpage customizations be carried over to SP Online's modern pages" or something like that) as the question sort of asks for a few things. Separate questions should be asked as different questions.

Comment: We are migrating from SP2103 to Online, however the new design is based on SPOnline in a classic setup. Regardless you are correct, needing to know if the classic design can be implemented on a modern site.